404 Error When Loading CSS Styles in a Spring Boot Application with Thymeleaf
Problem Description
I am developing a web application using Spring Boot and Thymeleaf. I have moved my CSS styles to the static folder and configured my project to serve static resources. However, when trying to load my CSS styles, I am getting a 404 error.
Project Structure
The structure of my project is as follows:
src
└── main
    ├── resources
    │   ├── static
    │   │   └── css
    │   │       └── styles.css
    │   └── templates
    │       └── fragments
    │           └── layout.html
    │       └── views
    │           ├── cliente.html
    │           ├── empleado.html
    │           ├── movimientos.html
    │           └── cuentas.html
    └── ...

Configuration
In my application.properties file, I have the following line for static folder:
spring.web.resources.static-locations=classpath:/static/
Relevant Code
In my layout.html file, I have the following line to include the CSS:
Observed Behavior
I can access the CSS file directly through the URL:
http://localhost:8080/css/styles.css
Steps I Have Tried

Verified the project structure.
Confirmed that the styles.css file is accessible directly.
Checked the browser console for errors.
Cleared the browser cache.
Restarted the server after making changes.

Expectation
My expectation is that once the error is resolved, all the views in my Spring Boot application will be able to correctly apply the CSS styles, including the sidebar. This will ensure that the layout and design elements are consistent and visually appealing across the entire application.
Can anyone help me understand why I am receiving a 404 error when trying to load my CSS styles in my Spring Boot application? What additional steps can I take to troubleshoot this issue?

Can you update your question to show how you import the CSS file in your layout.html file?
